# Flutter _CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast)

Tags: flutter

How Can I check if null?

```
  factory PostResult.createPostResult(Map<String, dynamic> object) {
return PostResult(
  caseId: object['case_id'],
  serial: object['serial'],
  movement: (object['movement'] as List)
      .map((e) => Content.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
      .toList()
);
```

}

I receive this error:

> Flutter _CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type
> 'List' in type cast)

EDIT: 11.04.2022
I solved the issue with this:

```
setState(() {
                                    postResult?.movement ??
                                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                            .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                          content: Text(
                                              'Nessuna riparazione trovata'),
                                        ));
                                  });
```

Comment: Looks like object['movement'] doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

It seems that object['movement'] is null.

```dart
movement: object['movement'] == null ? null : List<Content>.from(object["movement"].map((e) => Content.fromJson(e)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `??` operator to set default value if null.

In this case, `object['movement']` can be `null`(not exits will return null) and when it `null`, a empty list `[]` was used instead.

```dart
movement: (object['movement'] ?? [])
      .map((e) => Content.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
      .toList()

// When object['movement'] = null, movement = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:

1. `object['movement']` doesn't exist.
2. `object['movement']` it mayn't provide every time non null values.

Solutions:

1. check if the name is correct in JSON.
2. If it provides null then assign an empty list or any default list with the operator `??` .

Thanks.